# How do I get the return type of a function to be the input of another function in the same interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I created a function to memoize context values and return them as render props in React to avoid re-rendering when values change that I do not care about. (which works so thats great!) However, I am having trouble typing it.

The goal is to have the children function have the same type as the return type of accessor.

The part I am having a lot of trouble with is typing this part:

```
type ContextType = {
  state:{ a:number; b:number; }
  otherStuff:{ a:string; b:string }
}
export const ContextAccessor: <
  T extends {
    accessor: (ctx: ContextType) => ReturnType<T["accessor"]>;
    children: (ctx: ReturnType<T["accessor"]>) => JSX.Element;
  }
>(
  args: T
) => JSX.Element = ({ children, accessor }): JSX.Element =>
```

My accessor function is being typed as `accessor: (ctx: ContextType) => any` which then makes the function `children` have an input parameter type of any as well.

I think it is because `ReturnType<T["accessor"]>` does not actually work

The full code (without memoization) is below:

```
type ContextType = {
  state:{ a:number; b:number; }
  otherStuff:{ a:string; b:string }
}
export const ContextAccessor: <
  T extends {
    accessor: (ctx: ContextType) => ReturnType<T["accessor"]>;
    children: (ctx: ReturnType<T["accessor"]>) => JSX.Element;
  }
>(
  args: T
) => JSX.Element = ({ children, accessor }): JSX.Element => {
  const { state, modifiers, accessors } = useMyContext();

  const accessed = useMemo(
    () => accessor({ state, modifiers, accessors }),
    [state, modifiers, accessors]
  );

  return children(accessed)

};


export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <ContextAccessor accessor={(ctx) => ctx.state.a}>
      {(transfer) => (
        <div>
          <div>{JSON.stringify(transfer)}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </ContextAccessor>
  );
};
```

#### Edits of more things I have tried

The below I believe doesn't work because `ReturnType<Props<T>["accessor"]>` is typed as unknown and isn't generic.

```
type Props<T> = {
  accessor: (context: ContextType) => unknown;
  children: (ctx: ReturnType<Props<T>["accessor"]>) => JSX.Element;
};
export function StagingBuilderContext<T>(props: Props<T>): JSX.Element {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by adding an explicit type signature to the `accessor` prop function argument: `ctx` ~> `ctx: ContextType`.

```
export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <ContextAccessor accessor={(ctx: ContextType) => ctx.state.a}>
      {(transfer) => ( // inferred type for transfer is number
        <div>
          <div>{JSON.stringify(transfer)}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </ContextAccessor>
  );
};
```

With this assertion the `accessor` return value is immediately available, rather than having to be inferred from its usage, which enables correct inference on `children`. I'm not entirely certain about using `ReturnType<T["accessor"]>` in the `accessor` property, as this refers to itself, but it does appear to work correctly. An alternative would be to use a type parameter for the return type.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFCiSxwDecArqlgLJYgQA0bDgGEIAOxhYAHvAC%20cIiXKU8MWjRgBPMFjgjxUmABUtOgLzMacOKhjIJALhbJ7o1iABGWKAG447l26ePnAylnC8ACbABMBeqPbMKPY2UMCiAOa%20-ilp6SFheLhYqKjQ8YnOORlZyTCpGfmhNLhiNoJcGnoS0nDmABQAlL0AfO1dBgA849LG2sN9THJoKKIaQzQ0UgzwLaJt0zAAgrhFJdAJE2GGcAZYohHoTGFWhcWlUAl9%20JIJB7NYQ1Mo2wMFYUFE-wmhgA2gAiV5nKCwgC6w28zzguAAFsAADYRSiiT7fBIgsEQkxQuEI94o4aA0YAKQAygANAB0AFFcTw7jB0VZQvMClB0uVDDQGXAWRzubzxL04AtMTj8YSBDToCEBgkZVyeSA%20SMLFZdm0WDY7FgBJForEoKgNSc3mUQor2B0DoN0WEzfAaVgIu6ONxeH0MYNjZqoMrLRIbRAojE4k7Tu90DIBnwMdC49bwom7SmUM7EahkWEBj6rJRQeCVXiCXc%20gGIgMNjIfVtoDtWvBDMV4P0pU8a1g66IlRipmJukdS%208S2noKYmF8YD9dLODP8pd92Xn2cgZMMMVY13VkHsCF4peGrA%204AB6J9wAB6AH4zw%20JlEAG6no%20QFwL%20wAAUwLIAPIAHIHnUuTRBofSXtet4yBMT7-oBwEgZhYHYY%20AyhI%20GEHMcy5QNhVY0J2QA)

Comment: Why does it need the declaration in the `<ContextAccessor accessor={(ctx: ContextType) => ctx.state.a}>` line? Since we are already declaring it on line 14 (of your ts playground) Also, you are a god, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :-) The difference is that `(ctx: ContextType) => ctx.state.a` by itself already has the exact return type `number`, whereas `(ctx) => ctx.state.a` doesn't. So the type of `ctx` needs to be inferred based on how the function is used, and even though it does infer the type of `ctx` and the return type, this is a little too much to handle if there's also another function with an argument type to infer. TypeScript inference doesn't always fully explore all options, since it also needs to be performant.